# What is the story regarding birth of Surya

Tags: vishnu, vedas, puranas, upanishads, surya

I want to know the Puranic inscriptions regarding birth of Surya. How sun planet was created? When it was created? Why he is sometimes considered as direct expansion of Vishnu?

Comment: It can be found in the Markandeya Puranam here http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/markandeyapurana39.html

Comment: Sun is the son of Aditi and Sage Kashyapa. That is why he is called Aditya. Last question is answered here: [Why is Surya sometimes called Surya Narayana?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11416/why-is-lord-surya-also-called-suryanarayana)