# Do Vedas talk about avataras?

Tags: vedas, avatars

Do the Vedas talk directly about avataras?

Are there any direct references in main Vedic texts?

Note: kindly limit the references to  samhita, brahmanas, aranyaka and 10 upanishads.

Comment: Yes, Vamana incarnation is indirectly mentioned in Rigveda http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01022.htm check 18th Richa..will post after checking all the translations of this and Vishnu's other incarnations as Adityas..

Comment: Avataras are only a puranic concept. The RigVedic Vishnu is only a manifestation of the sun and the three steps refer to the movement of the sun.  Vamana's three steps are puranic and are obviously modeled on the Rig Vedic Trivikrama/vishnu.

Comment: @SK don't u think u r saying the fact but in reverse order. Actually, Surya is a manifestation of Vishnu and not opposite. Pls see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11416/why-is-lord-surya-also-called-suryanarayana And if Surya is an incarnation of Lord Vishnu then also incarnation concept can be proven in Vedas..Yes, three steps are also used for Sun sometimes but still it proves incarnation concept either by Vamana or Surya...

Comment: @YDS - I meant the yellow ball you see in the sky and not some mythological concept.  The rigvedic Vishnu represents is a way of lauding the sun.  The rigvedic vishnu hardly has any human attributes like arms and legs and so forth and the meaning "pervader" reflects the sun.  RigVeda also has "Surya" and "Savitr" which might have been other aspect of the Sun, with Vishnu representing its omnipresence and life-giving properties (which is why he became the sustainer in puranas).

Comment: yes because i dont want interpretation. only direct quotes. its ok if you dont want to comment. @YDS

Comment: @RakeshJoshi The Concept Of Diety changing from one form to another is present in the Vedas like in Rig Veda Indra deva and Rudra deva have been called multiform,while there is also legend in the Vedas where Indra deva changes himself to a form of foam to kill namuchi and as the legend narrated in shatapata brahmana and taitterya brahmana in the beginning of the world Lord Prajapati changes himself to a boar to pick up the earth.

Comment: If you see Lord vishnu s earliest  incarnations  from the Puranas/itihasas are actually forms like matsya,kurma,narasimha,varaha.they are not actually incartions like Born from a mother for ex shri Rama,parashurama,vamana avatar.

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda if you have the asked references then better to answer the question... Avatar in the sense xyz.god reincarnated on earth or other loka

Answer (score 13):

**Yes Vedas do talk about avataras.**
**Shathapatha Brahmana** tells us that Prajapati  assumed the Kurma Avatara. In **Shukla Yajur Veda** Samhita we find mantras which says Supreme Brahman took birth as Brahma. It also points towards Vaman Avatara.

> सुभू: स्वयम्भू: प्रथमोन्तर्महत्यर्णवे ।
>  दधे ह गर्भमृत्वियं यतो
>   जात: प्रजापतिः।।23.63।।
>
> Then originator of whole universe "Swayambhu Paramatma" (Supreme Soul)
>   in the middle of a great lake  ,laid down embryo timely ,from which
>   Brahma (Prajapati) was born.[**Yajurveda Samhita 23.63**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/yajurveda/v2.65)

Here we can see that ,the supreme soul himself incarnated as Brahma. Through womb.

---

[**Shatapatha brahmana**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/satapatha-brahmana-english/d/doc63327.html)  (7.5.1.5-10) is  mentioning Prajpati's avatara "Kurma" i.e. Tortoise.

> 5 And as to its being called 'kūrma' (tortoise);**Prajāpati, having
>   assumed that form,** created living beings. Now what he created, he
>   made; and inasmuch as he made (kar), he is (called) 'kūrma;' and
>   'kūrma' being (the same as) 'kaśyapa' (a tortoise), therefore all
>   creatures are said to be descended from Kaśyapa.

---

This mantra indirectly indicates towards **Lord Vishnu's "Narasimha Avatara**". i.e. Man-Lion form .As it says Lord Vishnu roam around the earth in the form of fierce Lion etc.

> प्र तद्विष्णु: स्तवते वीर्येण मृगो न भीमः कुचरो गिरिष्ठाः।
>   यस्योरुषु त्रिषु विक्रमणेष्वधिक्षियान्ति भुवनानि विश्वा ।।5.20।।
>
> Pra TadVishnuhu Stavate Viryena Mrugo Na Bhima Kucharo Girishtha
>
> YasyoRushu Trishu VikramNeShawaDhiKshiYanti Buvanani Vishwa
>
> Roaming around the earth in fiearc avatars like Lion etc. Residing on
>   mountains , all-pervading Vishnu is highly adorable through his
>   Manhood (Bravery). All the lokas resides under the three giant strides of him.  Vishnu deva is
>   praised here as thus.**Yajurveda Samhita 5.20**

Above  mantra  is also giving us indirect reference about Lord Vishnu's "Vaman Avatara" as it also talks about three strides of him.

---

As we know the concept of avatars is more clear in puranas. In Vedas we can see primary source of them. Vedas being abstract than puranas do not describe them in much details. The word avatar does not directly appear in the Vedic literature. But from the definition we can see that  [**avatara**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar)  also means"to make one's appearance" ,this concept is visible in vedas.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No word avatar in any of your verses !!!!!

Comment: Yes as I have mentioned the word avatar isn't there in vedic literature. But the concept is. And as the definition the word avatara also means making appearance so the concept of vedic avataras shouldn't necessarily be same as puranas nor necessarily the word.

Comment: it should specifically say that xyz god incarnated as abc on earth.. that is direct reference. Changing form is not avatar. for example shiva takes form of rudra, pancha mukha, eka mukha etc. Creating something is not avatara. The first verse is related to creation and not avatara of someone. I hope you are getting my point. Upanishat says that brahman created the jagat and entered the created jagat. That would mean we all are his avataras. but this avatara is specific related to a deity.

Comment: OP is asking for **direct references** which you have not given :) @SwiftPushkar

Comment: @Rickross - Thanks :-) Yes ,you are right and I am aware of that. But OP is asking about whether vedas  are talking about avatars or not. He didn't asked about the appearance of word avatar in vedas. After getting answer he is saying the word is not there in answer.

Comment: And I have already given the clarification about the word avatara in vedas in my answer. And I think first two examples are quite directly mentioning avataras. But still i will again search about some other direct clues ,which OP is talking abt. for his satisfaction.:)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar But what you have done is forcefully trying to arrive at a conclusion and that too you can do because you already know the stories of Puranas. But imagine if you don't know about the Puranic stories, Can u still say that these mantras are talking about avataras? Also OP is clearly asking about direct references --  But OP is asking about whether vedas are talking about avatars or not. -- You missed the word **directly** :)

Answer (score 8):

The concept of taking Avatara is not alien to Vedas. For example in Adhyatma Prakarana Sukta of AtharvaVeda Samhita avatara of Mahadeva is described:

> व्रात्य आसीदीयमान एव स प्रजापतिं समैरयत् ।।
>   स प्रजापति: सुवर्णमात्मन्नपश्यत्तत्प्राजनयत् ।।
>   तदेकमभवत्तल्ललाममभवत्तन्महदभवत्तज्जेष्ठमभवत्तद्ब्रह्माभवत्तत्तपोऽभवत्तत्सत्यमभवत्तेन प्राजायत ।।
>   सोऽवर्धत स महानभवत्स महादेवोऽभवत् ।।
>   स देवानामीशां पर्यैत्स ईशानोऽभवत् ।।
>   स एकव्रात्योऽभवत्स धनुरादत्त तदेवेन्द्रधनुः ।।
>   नीलमस्योदरं लोहितं पृष्ठम् ।।
>   नीलेनैवाप्रियं भ्रातृव्यं प्रोर्णोति लोहितेन द्विषन्तं विध्यतीति  ब्रह्मवादिनो वदन्ति ।।  [Atharva Veda 15:1]
>   
>   **There was Vratya. He roused Prajapati to action.** Prajapati beheld gold in himself and engendered it. That became unique, that became distinguished, that became great, that became excellent, that became Brahman, that became Tapas, that became Truth: **through that he (Vratya) was born. He grew, he became great, he became Mahadeva.** He gained the lordship of the Gods. He became Ishana. He became Eka Vratya. He held a bow, even that Bow of Indra. His belly is dark-blue (Nila), his back is red (Lohitam). With dark-blue he envelops a detested rival, with red he pierces the man who hates him: so the knowers of Brahman say.

So, the theory seen above is:

> Vratya (Supreme Being) ➡Takes birth through Prajapati➡becomes Mahadeva/Ishana/Eka Vratya

Answer (score 3):

Vamana Avatar is mentioned in Rig Veda:

> तरीणि पदा वि चक्रमे विष्णुर्गोपा अदाभ्यः |
>      अतो धर्माणि धारयन || 1.22.18
>
> **Viṣṇu**, the Guardian, he whom none deceiveth, **made three steps**; 
>    thenceforth Establishing his high decrees.

---

> पर विष्णवे शूषमेतु मन्म गिरिक्षित उरुगायाय वर्ष्णे |  य इदं दीर्घं
>
> परयतं सधस्थमेको विममे तरिभिरित पदेभिः || 1.154.3
>
> Let the hymn lift itself as strength to **Viṣṇu**, the Bull
>   far-striding, dwelling on the mountains, **Him who alone with triple
>   step hath measured this common dwelling-place**, long, far extended.

---

> यदा ते विष्णुरोजसा तरीणि पदा विचक्रमे | आदित ते || 8.12.27
>
> When **Viṣṇu**, through thine energy, **strode wide those three great steps
>   of his**, Then thy two beautiful Bay Steeds carried thee on.

---

Satapatha Brahamana mentions Matsya Avatar:

> [8th Chapter of First Brahmana:](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/satapatha-brahmana-english/d/doc63144.html)
>
> 1. In the morning they brought to Manu water for washing, just as now also they (are wont to) bring (water) for washing the hands. When he
>      was washing himself, a fish came into his hands.
> 2. It spake to him the word, 'Rear me, I will save thee!' 'Where from wilt thou save me?' 'A flood will carry away all these creatures: from
>      that I will save thee!' 'How am I to rear thee?'
> 3. It said, 'As long as we are small, there is great destruction for us: fish devours fish. Thou wilt first keep me in a jar. When I
>      outgrow that, thou wilt dig a pit and keep me in it. When I outgrow
>      that, thou wilt take me down to the sea, for then I shall be beyond
>      destruction.'
> 4. It soon became a jhaṣa (a large fish); for that grows largest (of all fish). Thereupon it said, 'In such and such a year that flood will
>      come. Thou shalt then attend to me (i.e. to my advice) by preparing a
>      ship; and when the flood has risen thou shalt enter into the ship, and
>      I will save thee from it.'
> 5. After he had reared it in this way, he took it down to the sea. And in the same year which the fish had indicated to him, he attended to
>      (the advice of the fish) by preparing a ship; and when the flood had
>      risen, he entered into the ship. The fish then swam up to him, and to
>      its horn he tied the rope of the ship, and by that means he passed
>      swiftly up to yonder northern mountain.
> 6. It then said, 'I have saved thee. Fasten the ship to a tree; but let not the water cut thee off, whilst thou art on the mountain. As
>      the water subsides, thou mayest gradually descend!' Accordingly he
>      gradually descended, and hence that (slope) of the northern mountain
>      is called 'Alarm's descent.' The flood then swept away all these
>      creatures, and Manu alone remained here.

Though it doesn't say Vishnu incarnated as Matsya, this description is almost the same as Matsya Avatar described in Ithihasa and Puranas.