# When avatar concept got introduced in Hinduism?

Tags: history, avatars

Vedas do not talk about avatars. When and why this concept got introduced in Hinduism?

Comment: Related: [Do Vedas talk about avataras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22618/277)

Comment: Vedas do talk about avataras. Read: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22618/do-vedas-talk-about-avataras/22639#22639

Comment: Your best bet is to post this on [History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com). If you ask here, you will only get theological/unsatisfying answers. A [similar question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/46093/historically-when-and-why-did-ganga-become-a-holy-river-is-it-after-sarasvat) about river Ganga was moved to History recently because it was attracting mythological answers here.

Answer (score 1):

**When avatar got introduced?**

First avatar appeared when Brahma was struggling to get earth back in this creation cycle. Lord Varaha appeared.

**Why avatar got introduced?**

The purpose of avatar is to restore dharma.

> Bg 4.8 — To deliver the pious and to annihilate the miscreants, as
>   well as to reestablish the principles of religion, I Myself appear,
>   millennium after millennium

Comment: I think Matsya and Kurma avatara appeared before Varaha.

Comment: @Pandya Varaha appeared twice, first at the beginning of day of Brahma to lift earth and then to kill Hiranyaksha in 6th/7th manvantara. Kurma and Matsya appeared in cakshusha and at the end of cakshusha manvantara respectively. Even Matsya appeared in the beginning of day of Brahma, which is first? I am not sure...