# Is it mentioned in the Vedas that God incarnates himself?

Tags: vedas

Is it mentioned in the Vedas that God incarnates himself? If not then do people believe it. Please give reference from the Vedas only.

Comment: The concept of Incarnation is not in the vedas. It is a concept first developed in the Samkhaya philosophy with 'persons merged in in Prakriti' according to difference in powers, with two classes - 'Kalpaniyamaka Isvara' or ruler for one cycle; and 'Isvarakotis' or those within a cycle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do Vedas talk about avataras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22618/do-vedas-talk-about-avataras)