# Why would Lord Vishnu try to kill himself in the Narada Purana?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, puranas, parvati, narada

> Narada Purana III.79.220-5 “The garland of hellish things is your ornament for the chest. The poisonous serpents viz. Vasuki and Sesa are your bangles. Your garments are the quarters (i.e. you are naked); the matted hair is what you have by way of your tresses. The white ash constitutes your unguent, the great bull is your vehicle. Your Gotra (spiritual lineage) and the family are not known. Your parents are unknown, your body is rendered ugly with hideous eyes.’ Even as the daughter of the mountain was saying this **Visnu spoke to her angrily**. ‘O goddess, why do you censure our lord of the universe, the lord of Devas. O gentle lady due to your nature of not controlling yourself you were not his beloved. You are like the evil vital breaths. O gentle lady, *it is my vow that I shall die where Isa is censured*.’ After saying this, **Hari attempted to cut off his head**. Mahesa caught hold of his hand and said, ‘Do not indulge in a risky venture. Everything that Parvati said is pleasing to me, not displeasing.” Tr. G.V. Tagare

Comment: Related or duplicate [was Vishnu beheaded in Shatapatha Brahmana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24755/3500)

Comment: Isn't the answer itself there in quotes? "I shall die where Isa is censured." Parvati's words , Hari's attempt to cut off his head and Shiva stopping him all this is  Leela of Supreme lord . This shows that Devi , Hari and Shiva are extreme devotees of each other , A perfect example of Ninda Stuti.

Comment: it kind of is but Visnu is considered the lord of the universe so why would he even attempt to commit suicide? Just cause of a vow?

Comment: @TheLogicalFanatic it was not suicide, it was self sacrifice

Comment: @TheLogicalFanatic - Yes agree with Anurag singh.

Comment: ok i guess this question but i wont delete it as more people need to know about this incident